# Problem mocking IHttpMessageHandler for both IHttpClientFactory and typed HttpClient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, httpclientfactory

I have some classes that I want to test that receive an `IHttpClientFactory`. Then they use that factory to create a `HttpClient` inside:

```
public class SampleClassUsingHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public SampleClassUsingHttpClientFactory(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        ...
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        await client.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
}
```

To test this class I mock the `HttpClientFactory` to always return an `HttpClient` with the `HttpMessageHandler` mocked:

```
public class WebApplicationFactoryWithMockedFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    public readonly Mock<HttpMessageHandler> HttpMessageHandlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    public readonly Mock<IHttpClientFactory> HttpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddScoped(srv => HttpMessageHandlerMock.Object);
            services.AddScoped(srv => HttpClientFactoryMock.Object);
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureHttpClientFactoryForMockedHttpClient(string url)
    {
        HttpClientFactoryMock
            .Setup(x => x.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(new HttpClient(HttpMessageHandlerMock.Object)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
            });
    }
```

Then I can set up the `HttpMessageHandlerMock` to behave as I need for the tests. Everything works fine.

On the other side, other classes that I want to test directly receive a typed `HttpClient`. For example:

```
public class SampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient : ISampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public SampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task Execute()
    {
        ...
        await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
}
```

The proper `HttpClient` is injected because there is the following registration in the `ServiceCollection`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ISampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient, SampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient((serviceProvider, httpClient) =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://this.is.a.sample");
    });
```

To test `SampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient` I register the typed `HttpMessageHandler` forcing to use the `HttpMessageHandlerMock` as the message handler:

```
public class WebApplicationFactoryWithTypedHttpClient : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    public readonly Mock<HttpMessageHandler> HttpMessageHandlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHttpClient<ISampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient, SampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient>()
                .ConfigureHttpClient(x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://this.is.a.sample.uri.for.tests"))
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => HttpMessageHandlerMock.Object);
        });
    }
}
```

Then I can set up the `HttpMessageHandlerMock` to behave as I need for the tests and everything is OK.

But some tests need to have registered both mocks (`HttpClientFactory` and a typed `HttpClient`):

```
public class WebApplicationFactoryWithMockedFactoryAndTypedHttpClient : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    public readonly Mock<HttpMessageHandler> HttpMessageHandlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    public readonly Mock<IHttpClientFactory> HttpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddScoped(srv => HttpMessageHandlerMock.Object);
            services.AddScoped(srv => HttpClientFactoryMock.Object);
            
            services.AddHttpClient<ISampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient, SampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient>()
                .ConfigureHttpClient(x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://this.is.a.sample.uri.for.tests"))
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => HttpMessageHandlerMock.Object);           
        });
    }
    
    public void ConfigureHttpClientFactoryForMockedHttpClient(string url)
    {
        HttpClientFactoryMock
            .Setup(x => x.CreateClient(It.IsAny<string>()))
            .Returns(new HttpClient(HttpMessageHandlerMock.Object)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
            });
    }
}
```

When executing the tests a `NullReferenceException` is thrown during dependency injection. It seems by the stack trace that .NET is internally using a `DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory` that is not able to create an instance of `HttpClient`. Maybe it is calling the mocked `HttpClientFactory` but the mock returns `null`, but it shouldn't because it is set up with a call to `ConfigureHttpClientFactoryForMockedHttpClient`. This is a fragment of the stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory`1.CreateClient(HttpClient httpClient)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<AddTypedClientCore>b__0(IServiceProvider s)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   ...
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you convert your code into a small repro GitHub repo?

Comment: I've found the problem when I was creating a minimal sample project to be uploaded to GitHub. I've posted the solution in the answer. Thanks @mu88 for suggesting me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem in my code. When you mock `IHttpClientFactory`, like I was doing, then every `HttpClient` is created using that mocked factory, so this line was doing nothing at all:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ISampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient, SampleClassUsingTypedHttpClient>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(x => x.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://this.is.a.sample.uri.for.tests"))
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => HttpMessageHandlerMock.Object);
```

The solution is to setup the mock of the `IHttpClientFactory` to return also a mocked `HttpClient` for typed client requests. It can be done with a call to a method like this:

```
public void ConfigureHttpClientFactoryMockForMockedTypedHttpClient<T>(Uri baseAddress)
{
    string httpClientName = typeof(T).Name;

    HttpClientFactoryMock
        .Setup(x => x.CreateClient(It.Is<string>(x => x.Equals(httpClientName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))))
        .Returns(new HttpClient(HttpMessageHandlerMock.Object)
        {
            BaseAddress = baseAddress
        });
}
```